# Http client implementation with HSTS support?

Tags: http, security, https, client, hsts

Most browsers support HSTS now. If my backend server calls a site which has HSTS enabled, is there existing http client implementation I can use that already supports HSTS?  I don't see that mentioned in Apache Commons HttpClient.  I basically want to turn http:// to https:// even before sending any requests over, as server redirects are not safe.  Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just configure your backend to always use https in requests?

Comment: The server is under a load balancer which is an HTTPS terminator. So, all requests going into the server always starts with http://, and all callback URLs composed based on the prefix of incoming requests will start with http://, which is problematic.  The callback URLs work with a browser, but not my own client app.

Comment: Did you find if apache http client or some other java client supports that? Also do you know if python reequest clients support HSTS?